# Aggregate Relationship - Initializing Class within Private from Seperate .cpp/.h

Tags: c++, class, aggregate-initialization

So I'm attempting to create a bankaccount program, that will essentially be using two separate classes derived from a separate .cpp/.h program called statistics (statistics.cpp / statistics.h) I have included the header files within the appropriate locations and ensured the I haven't made any case-sensitive errors. Moving forward. The issue I'm having is that I'm receiving an errors 
  -"warning: unused variable 'withdrawals' is not set."
  -"warning: unused variable 'deposits' is not set."

I have created my constructor/overload constructor appropriately in my statistics.cpp

```
 Statistics::Statistics(){
    size = 0;
    pData = nullptr;
    capacity = 0;
}


Statistics::Statistics(int capacity){
    pData = new double [capacity];
    size = 0;
    //int i = 0;
}
```

as well as defining it within my statistics.h file

```
class Statistics{
public:
    Statistics();//default constructor
    Statistics(int capacity);//...
```

And within my bankaccount.h file, I have added/created the two separate classes in an attempt to develop an aggregate relationship.

```
 //....
 private:
    double amount = 0;
    int transactions = 0;
    double value = 0;
    Statistics* deposits;
    Statistics* withdrawals;
 };
#endif
```

This is how I've initialized and set the classes within the bankaccount.cpp

```
int main(){
   //Statistics aStatistics; Constructor of Statistics
   //aStatistics.test(); Test function for Statistics .cpp/.h files (Was 
   //successful)

   bankaccount abankaccount;
   abankaccount.test();
   return 0;
}

void bankaccount::test(){

    cout << "Hello, Welcome to Boca Regional Bank." << endl;
    cout << "**********************************************" << endl;
    cout << "What is the expected amount of transactions for this month?" 
    <<endl;
    cin>> transactions;
    Statistics withdrawals = Statistics(transactions); //"Warning: unused variable 'withdrawals'"
    Statistics deposits = Statistics(transactions); //"Warning: unused variable 'deposits'"
    int userchoice;
    do{
       cout << "\n";
       userchoice = getuseroption();
       process(userchoice,transactions);
    } while (userchoice != 0);
 }

    void bankaccount::process(int option, int transactions){
       switch (option){
        case 1:
           double temp1;
           cout <<endl;
           cout << "You've chosen to deposit into your Bank Account."
           << endl;
           cout << "Your current balance is " << amount << endl;
           cout << "How much would you like to deposit?" << endl;
           cin >> temp1;
           while ((temp1 < 0) || (temp1 > 100000) ){
                cout << "You've entered an invalid amount, please try 
                again."<<endl;
                cout << "How many would you like to deposit?"<<endl;
                cin >> temp1;
           }
         deposit(&amount,temp1);
         if (temp1 > 0){ 
           deposits->add(temp1); //Implementation of one of the functions 
                                 //from the statistics class
                                 //At this point the program crashes

           }
         else if (temp1 == 0){
           break;
           }
         break;
....}
```

This is the Statistics .cpp/.h add(); function

```
void Statistics::add (double value){
    pData[size]=value;
    size++;
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve] that we can attempt to compile ourselves

Comment: Well, indeed you do not use these variables. I'm not sure how we can help more than stating the obvious here.

Comment: There are five separate files, I attempted to minimize it the best I can. If I structure it to mimic a single file, then the issue will not be replicated as stated in the description.

Comment: @PabloPorta: I didn't say it had to be a single file :-) If you can create a minimal .h and .cpp file, we can still attempt to compile. However, given the nature of the warning, I believe it's likely able to be reproduced in a single file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to initialize the `deposits` and `withdrawals` members of your `bankaccount` instance in `bankaccount::test()`. However, `Statistics withdrawals = Statistics(transactions);` just creates a local variable and initializes it. Since it is never used, the compiler warns that you probably meant to do something else (like initializing the members).

What you probably meant was:

```
withdrawals = new Statistics(transactions);
deposits = new Statistics(transactions);
```

If you do this, you have to `delete` these objects in the `bankaccount` destructor to avoid leaking memory. Modern C++ provides better ways to do this, but that's going offtopic.

Note: Class names in user code are usually in `CamelCase`, not `alllowercase`.

Comment: if i could kiss you in real life i would, thank you so much!